# How to print variable value in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a variable named '**`$uname`**' in a function from controller and I need to print the '`$uname`' value in the '`login_form_success`' under view.

**login.php**

```
public function uname_exist($uname) {
        $this->db->where('username', $uname);
        $query = $this->db->get('login');
        if (!$query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message(__FUNCTION__, 'Invalid Username');
            return FALSE;
        } else {

            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

login_form_success.php

```
<div class="alert alert-success">Welcome <?php echo $uname; ?> Signed in !</div>
```

Comment: `<?php echo $uname; ?>` is ok. but from where you load `login_form_success` view ?

Comment: is this AJAX call ??

Comment: No its not AJAX

Comment: are you loading login_form_success.php view?

Comment: Coz, when you load view, you can pass needed variable

Comment: Since I am new to php and codeigniter, please give some example so that I can understand

Comment: Instead of asking for examples here, you should probably rather be working through some beginner’s tutorial on the matter.

Comment: using CI standards is a best option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the value in **_SESSION** array as

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
```

and use the same value anywhere by using 
`$_SESSION['uname']`

Comment: Hi, But now I am getting an error as undefined index and My codes are :  public function user_exist($uname) {
session_start();
$this->db->where('username', $uname);
$this->db->get('login');
$_SESSION['username']=$uname;
}  and  
<div class="alert alert-success">You have Successfully Signed in 
    <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> !
</div>

Answer (score 1):

```
public function uname_exist($uname) {
        $this->db->where('username', $uname);
        $query = $this->db->get('login');
        if (!$query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message(__FUNCTION__, 'Invalid Username');
            $uname = "not exist";

        } else {
            $uname = "exist";

        }
        return $uname;
    }
```

use the $name return, and your html can got it by the same var name.

and better

```
public function uname_exist($uname) {
        $this->db->where('username', $uname);
        $query = $this->db->get('login');
        if (!$query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message(__FUNCTION__, 'Invalid Username');
            $unamehave = 'new person';

        } else {
            $unamehave = $uname;

        }
        return $unamehave;
    }
```

`<div class="alert alert-success">Welcome <?php echo $unamehave; ?> Signed in !</div>`

Comment: This would lead to confusion, if the user does not use identity comparison. `if (uname_exist($uname))` will evaluate to true even if it does not exist

Comment: And since we always go for perfection: the two identical return statements are unnecessary and can be reduced to only one. Helps in debugging situations as well

Answer (score 0):

This is only for future visitors:

As you accepted the `SESSION` suggestion, i suggest you to use [CI Session Library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) to follow framework standards:

You need to load session library in `autoload.php` as:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

now you can access the session library in any where in your project just because of `autoload.php` file, this will load session library automatically, now you can store session variables in your controller as:

```
$sessionArray = array('uname'=>$uname);
$this->session->set_userdata($sessionArray);
```

then, this session value should be accessible in your view file as like:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('uname'); // will print your name
```

You can also load your session library inside your controller file, if you are not interested to load in `autoload.php` as:

```
$this->load->library('session'); // but this will not accessible in other controllers.
```